# ¿Como imprimir el resultado un procedimiento almacenado usando PLSQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

pues la idea es esta tomar una fecha inicial y sumarle N meses y imprimir lineas desde la fecha dada hasta la fecha final.

Este es mi procedimiento almacenado

```
create or replace PROCEDURE tabla_test is
begin
    declare  
        contador int := 1;
        l_date1 date;
        l_date2 date;
        l_date3 date;
        l_date4 date;
       
   begin
   select to_char(to_date('2020','yyyy'), 'YYYY')--convertir varchar a año
   into l_date1
   from dual;
   
    select to_char(to_date(05,'MM'),'MM') -- convertir numero  a mes
    INTO l_date2
    FROM DUAL;
   
    SELECT to_date(l_date2||' '||l_date1,'MM/YYYY') --concatenar fecha
    into l_date3
    FROM DUAL;
   
    select add_months(to_date(l_date3,'MM/YY'),10) --limite
    into l_date4
    from dual;
   
    WHILE l_date3 <= l_date4
        Loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONTADOR: ' || TO_CHAR(CONTADOR) || 'ACTUAL: ' || TO_CHAR(l_date3));
        l_date3 := l_date3 + 1;
        contador := contador + 1;
        end loop;
   end;
end tabla_test;
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto manda este error

Error que empieza en la línea: 36 del comando :
BEGIN tabla_test; END;
Informe de error -
ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato
ORA-06512: en "APEX_EBS_EXTENSION.TABLA_TEST", línea 11
ORA-06512: en línea 1
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
"FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Comment: Revisando un poco el procedimiento creo que el error esta en la declaración de las variables, ya que estas asignando como tipo **date (fecha)** y en tus dos primeros select el tipo es **char (caracter)**, por lo que el error indica que el tipo de formato de variables donde deseas almacenar no comparten el mismo formato. Cambia el formato de tus variables según el dato a almacenar generado por la consulta.

Comment: Gracias Antonio